# creating all classes from sencha sdk

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to use the sencha sdk to generate my minified file.

I have my page set up on

http://www.mysite.localhost/ext/jobs/index.html

reading from just index.html is not easily possible. When i enter

```
sencha create jsb -a http://www.mysite.localhost/ext/jobs/index.html -p app.jsb3
```

I get the following jsb file.

```
{
    "projectName": "Project Name",
    "licenseText": "Copyright(c) 2011 Company Name",
    "builds": [
        {
            "name": "All Classes",
            "target": "all-classes.js",
            "options": {
                "debug": true
            },
            "files": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Application - Production",
            "target": "app-all.js",
            "compress": true,
            "files": [
                {
                    "path": "",
                    "name": "all-classes.js"
                },
                {
                    "path": "",
                    "name": "app.js"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "resources": []
}
```

ie it's not included all my classes. If i update

"path": "app/",
 "name": "app.js"

app-all.js is created correctly. But how can i get the controllers and views. There are a lot of files.  Does any one have any example mvc application jsb. My app is base on pandora.

app/app.js

```
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
    Ext.application({

        name: 'Pandora',
        models: ['Part', 'Material', 'Job', 'Process', 'Invoice', 'InvoiceDetail', 'PurchaseOrder'],
        stores: ['SalesContact', 'Parts', 'Materials', 'Jobs', 'AccountHandlers', 'JobTypes', 'Processs', 'Artwork', 'Varnish', 'VarnishType', 'PrintType', 'ProofRequired', 'InvoiceDetails', 'PurchaseOrders'],
  controllers: ['Part', 'Material', 'Job', 'Process', 'Invoice'],
        launch: function () {

            Ext.QuickTips.init();
            var cmp1 = Ext.create('App.view.Jobs', {
                renderTo: "form-job"
            });
            cmp1.show();
        }

    });
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form-job"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem myself at the moment. I am missing my ux, controllers, and views. It manages to find my stores and models. That's it. I am looking for how the **requires:** property comes into play with respect to the Viewport. You pass it an array of views, and one would infer the controllers with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

We got this working without the need for including everything in **Ext.Loader()** in *app.js*. Make sure you pass **Ext.Loader()** an array with your *Viewport* class. Still make sure you do the correct *uses:* and *requires:*. That way you final output for the jsb3 file contains everything.

I managed to sort this out on my end. I needed to use the **Ext.Loader()** in my *app.js* file. The general idea is you need to tell the loader where your source files are. Making sure your class file's are included in the build. Based on your code above for *app/app.js*.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });

// SDK builder required source files, use the class names.
Ext.Loader.require(['Pandora.view.Viewport']);

Ext.application({

    name: 'Pandora',
    models: ['Part', 'Material', 'Job', 'Process', 'Invoice', 'InvoiceDetail', 'PurchaseOrder'],
    stores: ['SalesContact', 'Parts', 'Materials', 'Jobs', 'AccountHandlers', 'JobTypes', 'Processs', 'Artwork', 'Varnish', 'VarnishType', 'PrintType', 'ProofRequired', 'InvoiceDetails', 'PurchaseOrders'],
    controllers: ['Part', 'Material', 'Job', 'Process', 'Invoice'],
    launch: function () {

        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        var cmp1 = Ext.create('App.view.Jobs', {
            renderTo: "form-job"
        });
        cmp1.show();
    }

});
```

I found that in your view and controller classes make sure if you have stores tied to your view (like a combobox) that you are adding **items** to the view itself in the **initComponent** and you use the **requires: 'MyApp.store.Users'** for the class. Or you will receive strange errors as the view will initialize before the store.

The **Ext.Loader.require()** must be placed before the **Ext.Application**. Once you have it all setup with the models and controllers, you'll want to add your views too.

You should be in a good place to create your jsb3 file now, and see that your models, views, and controllers are now part of the process for the build.

Comment: Some other helpful hints [Using the SDK tools](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?142768-Using-the-SDK-tools)

Comment: great, thanks for this. I'm going to have another session on this tomorrow. I'll post my findings.

Comment: Always happy to help. Don't forget to bump the answer as useful if it does help. We are supposed to have another session ourselves focusing on the sencha sdk and this subject.

Comment: Another thing thats worth adding is if you have authentication on your app, you'll want to disable it when generating your file in most cases. I do a detection on localhost and the PhantomJS/1.1.0 user agent to disable mine automagically when I want to regenerate my list of all-class files

Comment: @JamieSutherland interesting solution for auth. We made a whole separate directory with .html referencing our app just to get everything to play nice with the Sencha SDK tools because of the auth in our application.

Comment: The SDK tools are a bit awkward to get up and running with it must be said. I've had to dig into the source code a few times to workout odd behaviour. I wish they'd open source the SDK as I've made a few changes to the code to help when building multiple versions of the same app. Plus we could help with documenting how it works. Sounds like a topic blog post in the near future!

Comment: @subv3rsion - thanks your spot on. Re "make sure if you have stores tied to your view" can you expand on how best to do this. I've set up new question.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054269/adding-views-using-ext-sdk-store-issue

Comment: +100 was screwing around with this for a couple of hours until I saw your answer